# Does COleException::GetErrorMessage always return the error text in English?

Tags: c++, mfc, cexception

What would happen if the user's computer has a non-English , for example French? Would the text be in French then? I'm asking this because this is the behaviour of [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), unless the dwLanguageId parameter is specified to LANG_ENGLISH instead of LANG_NEUTRAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends which specific exception class is in use. There is nothing in the base `CException` class that sets or formats the error message. However, some of the `CException`-derived classes do call `FormatMessage` when returning their error messages. For example, `COleException::GetErrorMessage` calls

```
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
              NULL, m_sc,
              MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_SYS_DEFAULT),
              (LPTSTR) &lpBuffer, 0, NULL)
```

against the SCODE provided in AfxThrowOleException (note LANG_NEUTRAL).

Comment: Yes, the exception in question is a COleException and can be thrown by MS Word, which I automate with COM. Thanks for the answer.